# JAXB Ignore a method at runtime

Tags: jaxb

I have a class which is a 3rd party class. I can marshall and unmarshall in Java 7 but not Java 6. The reason is because it contains the following method
public PrintWriter getLogWriter() and PrintWriter does not have a default constructor. I am not using this method and the value is always null. I just want ignore this method, but I do not have the source code.
I am looking for the simplest way to do this.